# Delete multiple rows from mysql with checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox

I've got a query that displays a table with information about a message, I also have a column that gives the option to select the messages that the user wants to delete with a checkbox, once they have ticked the messages they want to delete, they then click on a submit button which takes them to the process page where the SQL statement to delete each selected message is made; however, the statement doesn't seem to work, this is what I have so far:

THE MESSAGE DISPLAY PAGE:

```
if ($_SESSION['user_session'] == "$current_user")
{
    {
     echo "<table border='1'>
     <tr>
     <th>Message ID</th>
     <th>Username</th>
     <th>Subject</th>
     <th>Message</th>
     <th>Delete?</th>
     </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['message_id'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['sub'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['message'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='" .     $row['message_id'] . "' /></td>";
          echo "</tr>";
             }
      echo "</table>";
     }
}
```

THE PROCESS PAGE WITH SQL STATEMENT:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
{
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check)
    {
    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX")
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    //select a database to work with
    $selected = mysql_select_db("XXX",$dbhandle)
    or die("Could not select examples");

    //execute the SQL query to update the "returned" field to 1 wherever the loan_id is     checked.
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM message WHERE message_id='$check'");
    }

              if ($result)
          {
              echo 'Messages Deleted';
          }
}
```

Comment: If you echo your generated delete query before executing it, I think you'll see your problem.

Comment: Is message_id always an integer then?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
{
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("XXX",$dbhandle) or die("Could not select examples");

    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM message WHERE message_id IN (" . implode(',', $_POST['check_list']) . ")", $dbhandle);
    if ($result !== false)
        echo 'Messages deleted.';
}
```

You obviously should implement some more testing of the contents of `$_POST['check_list']` before executing the query. We don't want evil people to do silly stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately it still doesn't seem to work; the message_id is being sent to the second page, however the SQL statement doesn't.

Comment: @cobra_fast: what is the purpose of (int) in "(int)$_POST['check_list'])"?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there's nothing wrong with your code, you should really try a `var_dump($check)` before the SQL query to output what it contains, and a `var_dump($_POST['check_list'])` at the very beggining of the second page.

Also, I suggest you to take out the database connection of the `foreach` as you are doing multiple innecesary connections, like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    // Output the variable $_POST['check_list']
    var_dump($_POST['check_list']);

    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    //select a database to work with
    $selected = mysql_select_db("XXX",$dbhandle) or die("Could not select examples");

    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
        // Output the $check variable to see what it contains
        var_dump($check);

        //execute the SQL query to update the "returned" field to 1 wherever the loan_id is     checked.
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM message WHERE message_id='$check'");

        // For each $check, verify what message_id got deleted
        if ($result) {
            echo 'Message ID Deleted: ' . $check;
        }
    }
}
```